# Linux kernel multiple file system drivers and performance

Tags: linux, performance, filesystems, nfs

I am not sure how Linux kernel handles multiple file system drivers and if an inode lookup for each given mounting point in file system interferes with other mounting points, or is there something else that will make the system perform slower in case there is some slow file system driver in the kernel but mounted file system that is managed by that driver is almost not in use.

My concern is NFS. So does an NFS driver slow down a Linux kernel and/or user space assuming that operation that requires a fast disk I/O is being performed on a local file system?

I assume that having `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `PATH` may slow down the system as `ld` and/or `bash` will try to lookup stuff in directories on NFS. But does NFS really interfere somehow when I open a file on a local filesystem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each inode points to a single file system, and IO to/from that inode is handled solely by that filesystem driver, regardless of which other filesystem drivers are loaded into the kernel.

In particular, NFS does not per se slow down other IO. Of course, if the system is getting hammered over NFS, then also local IO for that filesystem will be slower, but that is because of the high IO rate to a shared resource (the disks underlying the filesystem), not anything specific to NFS. IOW, if the NFS subsystem is idle it should not in any way affect local IO.

And no, NFS will not interfere if you're looking up a file on a local filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

I mount nfs from remote server to /nfs(50 directory and 100000 files).
Then create,write and read files in other direcroty five times:

```
time for i in {1..1000};do touch $i;done
time for i in {1..1000};do echo "$i" > $i;done
time for i in {1..1000};do cat "$i" > /dev/null;done

create: average 7.903s
write: average 0.068s
read: average 7.682s
```

Then umount /nfs and test again

```
create: average 7.923s
write: average 0.048s
read: average 7.782s
```

Then restart server and test again(without /nfs)

```
create: average 7.901s
write: average 0.052s
read: average 7.582s
```

If the effect exists, it is very small.
Server: HP ProLiant DL160 G6, Linux 2.6.32-24-generic-pae

Comment: So when you restart the server, NFS is not mounted and NFS kernel driver is not loaded. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

The above answers, while correct, did not address the library searching that goes on with every system call that you asked about.  In short, I ran a test on lightly loaded systems and the system calls against NFS took no additional, statistically significant time.  I have an NFS mount point `/data/media` that I added to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and then I use `strace` to track system calls and their time to execute.

For those unfamiliar with starting an executable, every shared library must be found and loaded before execution passes to `main()`, which is where the probing of NFS could be a potential problem.  By adding an NFS mounted directory to the library loader's path, we should be able to do simple timing tests.  Obviously, if an NFS server is not responding, the execution of all new processes will likely halt, especially if the mount point is mounted as "hard," that is, without the "intr" option.  This is partially because the shell will search the `PATH` for a new program's name and gets stuck on the NFS mount point.  That is not what we are about to measure.

Here is the shell code to run a program and document the syscall execution time.  Note again that I only have one NFS mount point, `/data/media`, in LD_LIBRARY_PATH just to keep it simple.

```
strace -T -e open java -version  2>&1 |\
perl -ne 'if (m/\/data\/media.*<(\d+\.\d+)>/) { \
             print "nfs,$1\n";
          } elsif (m/<(\d+\.\d+)>/) {
             print "local,$1\n";
          };'
```

The original strace output is similar to this

```
open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/bin/../lib/amd64/jli/tls/x86_64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000041>
```

And the output is similar to this

```
local,0.000030
local,0.000031
nfs,0.000042
nfs,0.000029
nfs,0.000029
nfs,0.000030
local,0.000028
local,0.000027
local,0.000027
```

I chose perl because I'm comfortable with it, but any text filtering will do.

I threw these number in a spreadsheet and sorted them so that I could show you this table

```
               Avg (s)     Max (s)   Min (s)
NFS lag (s) -0.0000072   -0.000529  0.000007
NFS lag (%)    -17.84%     -90.74%    36.84%
```

Quite obviously, you should try throwing your system cache out the window before doing this test and see if it changes things, but that's not the normal condition for your system.

In case you have trouble interpreting the table, there were cases where NFS was actually faster than the local filesystem.  This is counter-intuitive until you consider that VFS caching is probably going on.

Therefore, I conclude that for at least this little tiny test, having an NFS mount point in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH does not affect load time for executables.  As long as the NFS server is up...